# Fastest way to scrape web pages all within one web site

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

I have a C# app that needs to scrape many many pages within a certain domain as fast as possible. I have a Parallel.Foreach that loops through all of the urls (multi-threaded) and scrapes them using the code below:

```
private string ScrapeWebpage(string url, DateTime? updateDate)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            Stream responseStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            string html = null;

            try
            {
                //create request (which supports http compression)
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Pipelined = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
                if (updateDate != null)
                    request.IfModifiedSince = updateDate.Value;

                //get response.
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                    responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                    responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                //read html.
                reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {//dispose of objects.
                request = null;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                    response = null;
                }
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    responseStream.Close();
                    responseStream.Dispose();
                }
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return html;
        }
```

As you can see, I have http compression support and have set request.keepalive and request.pipelined to true. I'm wondering if the code I'm using is the fastest way to scrape many web pages within the same site or if there's a better way that will keep the session open for multiple requests. My code is creating a new request instance for each page I hit, should I be trying to use just one request instance to hit all of the pages? Is it ideal to have pipelined and keepalive enabled?

Comment: "scrape as fast as possible" - note that unless you have some agreement with the site owner, this will get you banned as quickly as possible; nobody likes unauthorized scrapers, especially if they are also an unintended DoS (and opening a new connection for every request can overwhelm many a server)

Comment: To the point: yes, keepalive and pipelining will get you much better performance (as there's lower setup/teardown overhead).

Comment: Yes definitely, it's always a fine line with scraping not too much to stay below radar but fast enough to keep your data up to date. The HttpWebRequest object has a default timeout of 100 seconds, I set it to 10 seconds and then was getting a ton of timeouts. I realized something was amiss, then changed the default connection limit from 10 to 100K and that resolved all timeouts and now all the web requests are super fast.. too fast.. I need to throttle this now. :)

Comment: @Justin there seems to be an error in you algorithm. have you been getting any error yet with the gzip stuff

Comment: @Smith No the gzip compression has worked great. Are you saying you need the code related to that?

Comment: I realise this is a pretty old post, but for anyone interested, you can make this a tiny bit faster by using `IndexOf` instead of `.ToLower.Contains`. `IndexOf` allows you to ignore case. The `IndexOf` function runs approximately 18% quicker than `.ToLower.Contains`. `response.ContentEncoding.IndexOf("gzip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1` instead of: `response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out what I was missing was this:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000;
```

Comment: can you mark your post as the answer, i'd like to know how you use this function so that it supports keep alive?

Comment: Can you give example how you use this function between subsequent calls so that it keeps alive?